# Append Rows in a dataframe from an existing dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a dataframe like this:

df1

```
                      V1   V2   V3     A        PF         KVA          KW  
Timestamp                                                                    
2017-04-01 07:00:00  254  243  246  1385  0.910143  594.107753  540.722928   
2017-04-01 08:00:00  242  249  244  1058  0.695257  448.951720  312.136890   
2017-04-01 09:00:00  242  240  240  1051  0.690657  438.093235  302.572222   
2017-04-01 10:00:00  251  241  242  1209  0.794486  512.329064  407.038122
```

I have another dataframe in the same format. suppose df2

I want to append rows of df2 in df1 using for loop.

I have used this:

```
hist1 = df1

for x in df2.iterrows():
    x = DataFrame(list(x))
    print x
    hist1.append((x),ignore_index=True)
```

but coudn't able to do it. Can anybody suggest me the correct way to do it?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is necessary loop? `df = pd.concat([df1, df2])` or `df = df1.append(df2)` should work

Comment: @jezrael,Yes, i want to use loop and do some calculations based on each data.

Answer (score 0):

If loop is necessary use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), but here is necessary assign back output, because it is not `pure python append`:

```
for i, x in df2.iterrows():
    df1 = df1.append(x)
```

---

```
df2 = df1 * 100
for i, x in df2.iterrows():
    df1 = df1.append(x)

print (df1)
                          V1       V2       V3         A         PF  \
Timestamp                                                             
2017-04-01 07:00:00    254.0    243.0    246.0    1385.0   0.910143   
2017-04-01 08:00:00    242.0    249.0    244.0    1058.0   0.695257   
2017-04-01 09:00:00    242.0    240.0    240.0    1051.0   0.690657   
2017-04-01 10:00:00    251.0    241.0    242.0    1209.0   0.794486   
2017-04-01 07:00:00  25400.0  24300.0  24600.0  138500.0  91.014300   
2017-04-01 08:00:00  24200.0  24900.0  24400.0  105800.0  69.525700   
2017-04-01 09:00:00  24200.0  24000.0  24000.0  105100.0  69.065700   
2017-04-01 10:00:00  25100.0  24100.0  24200.0  120900.0  79.448600   

                              KVA            KW  
Timestamp                                        
2017-04-01 07:00:00    594.107753    540.722928  
2017-04-01 08:00:00    448.951720    312.136890  
2017-04-01 09:00:00    438.093235    302.572222  
2017-04-01 10:00:00    512.329064    407.038122  
2017-04-01 07:00:00  59410.775300  54072.292800  
2017-04-01 08:00:00  44895.172000  31213.689000  
2017-04-01 09:00:00  43809.323500  30257.222200  
2017-04-01 10:00:00  51232.906400  40703.812200
```

---

```
df2 = df1 * 100
for i, x in df2.iterrows():
    df1 = df1.append(x, ignore_index=True)

print (df1)
        V1       V2       V3         A         PF           KVA            KW
0    254.0    243.0    246.0    1385.0   0.910143    594.107753    540.722928
1    242.0    249.0    244.0    1058.0   0.695257    448.951720    312.136890
2    242.0    240.0    240.0    1051.0   0.690657    438.093235    302.572222
3    251.0    241.0    242.0    1209.0   0.794486    512.329064    407.038122
4  25400.0  24300.0  24600.0  138500.0  91.014300  59410.775300  54072.292800
5  24200.0  24900.0  24400.0  105800.0  69.525700  44895.172000  31213.689000
6  24200.0  24000.0  24000.0  105100.0  69.065700  43809.323500  30257.222200
7  25100.0  24100.0  24200.0  120900.0  79.448600  51232.906400  40703.812200
```

EDIT:

I think better is create new DataFrame and then `append` only once:

```
df2 = df1 * 100

L = []
for i, x in df2.iterrows():
    x = x * 2
    #append Series to list, no assign back
    L.append(x)


df3 = pd.concat(L, 1).T
print (df3)
                          V1       V2       V3         A        PF  \
2017-04-01 07:00:00  50800.0  48600.0  49200.0  277000.0  182.0286   
2017-04-01 08:00:00  48400.0  49800.0  48800.0  211600.0  139.0514   
2017-04-01 09:00:00  48400.0  48000.0  48000.0  210200.0  138.1314   
2017-04-01 10:00:00  50200.0  48200.0  48400.0  241800.0  158.8972   

                             KVA           KW  
2017-04-01 07:00:00  118821.5506  108144.5856  
2017-04-01 08:00:00   89790.3440   62427.3780  
2017-04-01 09:00:00   87618.6470   60514.4444  
2017-04-01 10:00:00  102465.8128   81407.6244
```

```
df1 = df1.append(df3)
print (df1)
                          V1       V2       V3         A          PF  \
2017-04-01 07:00:00    254.0    243.0    246.0    1385.0    0.910143   
2017-04-01 08:00:00    242.0    249.0    244.0    1058.0    0.695257   
2017-04-01 09:00:00    242.0    240.0    240.0    1051.0    0.690657   
2017-04-01 10:00:00    251.0    241.0    242.0    1209.0    0.794486   
2017-04-01 07:00:00  50800.0  48600.0  49200.0  277000.0  182.028600   
2017-04-01 08:00:00  48400.0  49800.0  48800.0  211600.0  139.051400   
2017-04-01 09:00:00  48400.0  48000.0  48000.0  210200.0  138.131400   
2017-04-01 10:00:00  50200.0  48200.0  48400.0  241800.0  158.897200   

                               KVA             KW  
2017-04-01 07:00:00     594.107753     540.722928  
2017-04-01 08:00:00     448.951720     312.136890  
2017-04-01 09:00:00     438.093235     302.572222  
2017-04-01 10:00:00     512.329064     407.038122  
2017-04-01 07:00:00  118821.550600  108144.585600  
2017-04-01 08:00:00   89790.344000   62427.378000  
2017-04-01 09:00:00   87618.647000   60514.444400  
2017-04-01 10:00:00  102465.812800   81407.624400
```